# How to add event binding for a custom event with a colon ":" Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, event-binding

I try to add an event binding for an event with a name `scope:change` for a web-component in Angular:

```
<web-comp
  [name]="name"
  (scope:change)="onScopeChange($event)"
>
</web-comp>
```

However, the compiler gives Error: Unexpected global target 'scope' defined for 'change' event.
Supported list of global targets: window,document,body.

I want to ask is there any syntax I could use in this case, or do I have to manually addEventListner in the component somehow?

Comment: (change) is a valid syntax for angular if that is what you are looking for!

Comment: No, the event name is exactly `scope:change`. It is the naming convention of that web-component

Comment: Are you any third party library. If you could post the link.

Comment: Yes, it is 3rd party, but it is internal, so I cannot post the link. The web component will emit few events with the colon convention, e.g. `scope:change`, `product:failed`,...

Comment: I doubt anyone would be able to suggest the proper syntax without looking at the doc, as it is a private library. If possible, do post a query on any support forum/ email of that library.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue on this in the Angular repo: [\[Bug\]: Namespaced Custom Events](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28491)

Answer (score 0):

The event name parser only checks for the first instance of `:` so we can prefix the event name with `:` to trick it.

Using your example:

```
<web-comp
  [name]="name"
  (:scope:change)="onScopeChange($event)"
>
</web-comp>
```

I've posted this workaround with additional details on the corresponding issue in the Angular repo [[Bug]: Namespaced Custom Events](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28491#issuecomment-1865476756)